# Where is jQuery installed in VS2015?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2015

I just got the RTM release of VS2015 and I wanted to start with an empty project and while installing some nugets I see that jQuery isn't to be found on the disk.

I was expecting it to be placed in wwwroot but it's missing.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery is installed as a bower dependency so it's on dependencies, bower.

you can see all your client script dependencies in bower.json

if it's not on disk, it will after you do dnu restore

Comment: I'm lost, what is and how do you do a DNU restore?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of project you chose. If you chose a web project it should be under content/scripts. Otherwise just use package manager console and install it:

```
install-package jquery
```

Comment: I did that but nothing is downloaded. I choose the new preview template.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it through Nuget Package manager console,If your project is not a web project.If your project a web project then check under content/scripts.If there also you can't find it,then install jquery manually.

Comment: This is the new ASP.NET 5 empty template. I have no content/scripts nor is it created